# How to get the numbers that appear a certain amount of times in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I should have asked in a simpler way without showing what I had been trying to do.
Supposing I have this array:

```
function scr(array, n){

}
scr([187,187,187,187,187,62,62,43,43,43,43,43,5,5,5], 5)
```

I would like to get an array that shows the numbers that appear a certain amount of times. In that case, I would like the numbers that appear 5 times and so give:

```
[187,43]
```

How can I do that, please?

PS: Sorry for the complicated previous question

Comment: Please share your work sofar

Comment: bahahahaha ... an empty function is your attempt!!! that's priceless

Comment: `that appear 5 times` ... exactly 5 times? or 5 or more times? is it five times in the example because there's a 5 as the last entry in the array? why is it "in that case ... 5 times" ... what is "that case"? an arbitrary random number? or is it 5 because that's the maximum number of times any element appears? ... so if there were  6 x 43's the result is just `[43]` ... there's so much you haven't explained in the question, and your feeble attempt doesn't help clarify anything

Comment: Yes, exactly 5 times

Comment: Why 5 times? what is the logic? is it an arbitrary number  - if so, I would've expected `function scr(array, n)` so that you can pass in `5`, or `6`, or `2,481,356,121`

Comment: Sorry, I changed the function with an n.

Comment: ok, because I did have a solution for getting the value that appears maximum times `a=>Array.from(newSet(a),v=>({v,n:a.filter(i=>i===v).length})).sort((a,b)=>b.n-a.n).filter((x,i,a)=>x.n===a[0].n).map(({v})=>v);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to group items in an array, giving you a count of each number, and then filter it by the numbers with a count of 5:

```js
const input = [187,187,187,187,187,62,62,43,43,43,43,43,5,5,5];
const count = input.reduce((a, num) => {
  a[num] = (a[num] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});
const fives = Object.entries(count)
  .filter(([, occurrences]) => occurrences === 5)
  .map(([num]) => Number(num));
console.log(fives);
```

Comment: this does change them to strings though one downside but i like your approach :)

Comment: You can change the `.map(([num]) => Number(num))` expression to simply `.map(Number)`, like I do in my answer.

Comment: @Jorjon In my snippet, the array at the point before the `.map` there is an array of [num, occurrences], so I have to destructure the `num` out and cast *it* to Number explicitly; can't call `Number` on an array unless the array has only one element.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most performant but readable, its a good canidate for reduce

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```js
const numbers = [187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 62, 62, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 5, 5, 5];

function equalFive(array, num) {
   return array.filter(i => i === num).length === 5;
}

function getNumbersThatAppearFiveTimes(array) {
  return array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if (!prev.includes(curr) && equalFive(array, curr)) {
      return [...prev, curr]
    }
    return prev;
  }, []);
}
console.log(getNumbersThatAppearFiveTimes(numbers))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), which already have many of this functions built in so you your codebase can be cleaner.

```js
const inputArray = [187,187,187,187,187,62,62,43,43,43,43,43,5,5,5];
const inputValue = 5;

const count = _.countBy(inputArray); // count each instance of values
const equality = _.pickBy(count, x => x === inputValue); // filter values with 5 appearances
const output = Object.keys(equality).map(Number); // convert to desired format

console.log(output); // [43, 187]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input_array = [187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 62, 62, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 5, 5, 5];
//Sort input array
input_array.sort();

var output_array = [];
var count = 0;
var current = input_array[0];
for(var i = 0; i < input_array.length; i++){
  //Loop until change to next number
  //Check if total quantity equals 5
  if(input_array[i] != current){
    //save into output if equals 5
    if(count == 5){
      output_array.push(current);
    }
    //reset counter
    current = input_array[i];
    count = 1;
  }else{
    count++;
  }
}

console.log(output_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Array#reduce() to map counts into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object then Array#filter() to return results

```js
function scr(array, n) {
  const counts = array.reduce((a, c) => a.set(c, (a.get(c) || 0) + 1), new Map);
  return [...counts.keys()].filter(v => counts.get(v) >= n);
}


const input = [187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 62, 62, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 5, 5, 5];

console.log(scr(input, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a counter and filter the *nth* element of counting with a single loop.

```js
function scr(array, n) {
    var count = Object.create(null);
    return array.filter(v => (count[v] = (count[v] || 0) + 1) === n);
}

console.log(scr([187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 62, 62, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 5, 5, 5], 5));
```